# X-Axis label mixes time with date

Tags: highcharts

My datetime-axis is apparently a bit confused. I'm showing a chart for a week-interval and the labels sometimes show something like this:

> 16:00 - 14.02. - 15.02. - 19.02. - 20:00

Is there a way to tell the axis to stick with one type of label and not mix them?

Answer (score 0):

You can set tickInterval http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickInterval or define timelabels http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats

Comment: I'm already using tickInterval (70), that's neccessary for the intraday-Charts to start at 09:00. I'm using the same config for all charts (Intraday, week, month, year), so there's no way for me to change the tickInterval for week-charts.
dateTimeLabelFormats isn't helping either, since I already set them to display the date-labels in the desired format.

Comment: tickInterval for dateTime axis should be defined as time in miliseconds.